# NET core - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a ', .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, console-application, .net-6.0

I have converted .NET Framework 3.5 TestAPP to .NET 6 TestAPP  and worked well.
i have an Automation project(C++ project) which was using .NET Framework 3.5 TestAPP.dll to run the tests, but right now i have replaced the .NET Framework 3.5
.dll with .NET 6 TestAPP i.e. TestAPP.dll
when i ran the exe in command line , i have got an error as

> "Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
> or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
> located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Please let me know if anything needs to be corrected.

Comment: Did you try to search for that error number? There are a lot of results to look for

Comment: Can you post your web.config file?

Comment: This is not a web application , this is for a SDK and i didn't find any config file in the automation project. (automation project is C++ project which is referring to new .NET 6 dll)

Comment: Hi @Steve , i have checked the error number  but didn't find any clue

Comment: If you are copying a dll to another project manually, it either needs to include all its dependencies as well (like the v6 version of System.Runtime) or they need to be installed into the local machine GAC so they can be found globally. If you are on another machine, this should work if you install the .Net 6 SDK

Comment: @LukeBriner i am running in  the same machine which has .NET6 installed .

Comment: The error says that it found a dll of the wrong version. If the test app also references another version, you will need to use an assembly redirect to get all references to point to the v6 one

Answer (score 7):

Resolved the error  by changing the C++/CLI properties from visual studio project properties , which was referring to .NET framework earlier and i have changed the property as .NET core runtime(clr:netcore) and it is internally handled all GAC changes and worked well.
Hope it might help someone .
[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you are using .Net versions earlier than .Net 6 and have installed .Net SDK 8 on your machine, this issue may occur.  .Net 8 does not support duplicate files in the publish directory. As a result it is failing to load runtime.

Workaround: Install .NET 7 SDK from here (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0).

Comment: I have a sln of dotnet core 3.x and I have upgraded it to dotnet 8 and you recommendation worked, thanks @towhid

Comment: why is this a thing?!

Answer (score 4):

When upgrading an app to a later .NET version, edit your csproj file and make sure there is no `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` node in there that someone may have inserted manually.
This will not be updated automatically when switching .NET versions

Answer (score 2):

Try to install .net6 SDK !!! (not .net6 runtime).You can use the 'dotnet --info'
to check the dotnet info by windows shell.
If it does not contains .net6 SDK, install it.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydsMz.png)

Comment: Thank you! This was the real issue for me. I just had the runtime installed. Installing the SDK solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was due to worng Default Project in Package Manager Console, if you are running EF migrations or something that is in a project that need to get info from the API make sure you are targetting the right project, also try clean + build first.

Answer (score 0):

The running project returned this error. When I changed it to the way in the image, the error was solved.

[Project>Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPhhX.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31944812)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to remove all package dependencies and add them again using Nuget package manager. Only then did the project start working again.

Answer (score 0):

It happened after installing .NET 8.0. I think that Microsoft installer uninstalled the .NET 6.0 SDK and installed .NET 8.0 SDK. I don't know why and also don't know why the problem happens... but it was solved...

My solution was install the .NET 6.0 SDK latest version. After that, closed all VS instances and open again. Your project should compile and run normally.