# Unable to deploy .Net 6 code into K8s, pod status is CrashLoopBackOff note: this was a working code when it's .Net 5, migrating to .Net 6 it's not

Tags: .net, kubernetes, dockerfile

Same code is working fine in Visual Studio 2022... But When I deploy in K8s pod it's crashing.. the same code was working still yesterday with .Net5.. once the dev team migrated the code into .Net 6 now it's not working..

Getting the below error in pod logs,

Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

To install the .net SDK and run time I have the beow line in my docker file,

RUN dnf install dotnet-sdk-6.0.106 -y

RUN dnf install dotnet-runtime-6.0.6 -y

Comment: Maybe the dev team has not migrated correctly? ... To be honest just renaming project file content from net5 to net6 is not enough. Maybe they have not migrated the nuget packages?

Comment: Thank you Martin for your response,  in that case code should not work even in local over visual studio isn't it ?

Comment: Never trust Visual Studio. Sometimes it internally "knows" where to load libraries. Never the less which base/build/runtime images do you use for your docker container?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NET core - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a ', .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71217706/net-core-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-6-0-0-0-cul)

Comment: Hi  @Martin, here is my docker file how it look like, Note: Dotnet build and publish we are doing in jenkinsfile which we are following for all microservices deployment and it's working fine..

Comment: FROM rockylinux
#dockerfile metadata
LABEL hr.ht="sometext" \
maintainer="sometext" \
version="1.0" \
description="This Dockerfile builds and runs application name"
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development \
DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
#install wget
RUN yum -y install wget
#Packages to be installed ans per the instruction
RUN dnf install dotnet-sdk-6.0.106 -y
RUN dnf install dotnet-runtime-6.0.6 -y
RUN yum install -y sudo
RUN sudo update-ca-trust enable; sudo update-ca-trust extract
RUN cd /opt/publish 
RUN mkdir /opt/publish/config

Comment: RUN touch /opt/publish/config/environment.config.json
RUN ln -sf /opt/publish/config/environment.config.json /opt/publish/appsettings.json
WORKDIR /opt/publish
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "applicationname.dll"]

Comment: You can also update your question with the Dockerfile to have it formatted :) ... Have you tried building you application in docker? Normally if you have built your source you dont need the sdk installed.

Comment: Try to use the default way [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows#create-the-dockerfile) to validate if your dockerfile has a problem or your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246092/discussion-between-em-k-and-martin).

Answer (score 0):

Hi Martin thanks for your time and guidance, this issue is resolved now (last week itself)..

By adding this into the .csproj ProprtyGroup
< AnalysisLeve > 6.0 < AnalysisLevel >